# How to get different tables data?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP code to get the data from database with 2 different table 'tbl_products' & 'tbl_productphotos' with same column "ProductID", but I can't get images from the 'tbl_productphotos'.

```
tables data is: 'tbl_products'
ProductID    Title        Description   tilename  
  36        T-shirt       T-Shirt Red   Glass Tile
  37         Pant          Pant Black   Glass Tile

'tbl_productphotos'
id     ProductID         photo
1       36            image1.jpeg
2       36            image2.jpeg
3       37            imagepant.jpeg
```

my query is :

```
<?php
$sql="select tbl_products.*,tbl_productphotos.* from tbl_products inner join tbl_productphotos on tbl_products.ProductID=tbl_productphotos.ProductID where tbl_products.tilename='Glass Tile' ";    
    $qex=mysql_query($sql);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qex))
          {
?>
```

& print here :

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ProductID'];?>">


                        <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 isotope-item websites" style="float: left">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-centered-icons">
                                    <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">

                                        <img src="images/products/big/<?php echo $row['photo'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" height="200px" width="200px">
                                        <span class="thumb-info-title">
                                            <span class="thumb-info-inner"><?php echo $row['Title'];?></span>
                                            <span class="thumb-info-type"><?php echo substr($row['Description'],0 ,37);?></span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="thumb-info-action">
                                            <a href="portfolio-single-project.html">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-primary"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="img/projects/project.jpg" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                                                <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
```

Comment: could you update tilename column as well?

Comment: yes i did please check

Comment: Also update while loop implementation

Comment: As you will have seen from the various edits to your questions, we do not add "ASAP" and signatures here. This has been remarked to you several times, so we are now entering a point where you are doing it wilfully and then waiting for a volunteer editor to clear up the mess you keep making. If you persist, your downvote tally will get to the point where you hit the automatic question ban. So, it really is in your own interests to write better questions, and to stop begging for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could define alias for the same column name:  `products_ProductID` and `productphotos_ProductID`.

```
$sql  =  "select tbl_products.*,tbl_productphotos.*, tbl_products.ProductID as products_ProductID, tbl_productphotos.ProductID as productphotos_ProductID from tbl_products inner join tbl_productphotos on tbl_products.ProductID=tbl_productphotos.ProductID where tbl_products.tilename='Glass Tile' ";
```

Comment: no sir its not working even now its not gtting first table "tbl_products' table other details like Title , Description. Please check again & reply me 
Regards- Cue

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$sql = "select t1.*,t2.*
from tbl_products t1, tbl_productphotos t2
where t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
and t1.tilename = 'Glass Tile' 
and t1.ProductID = 36";
```

Comment: no sir not working. please check again and sir one thing that image1.jpeg will store in folder"big" & image2.jeg in folder "medium" of ProductID = 36 & imagepant.jpeg will store in folder "big" of ProductID = 37

Comment: no its not gaving me any error. but not getting & showing images too

Comment: yes sir i tried manyally to get image from the folder "big" & its working & showing me image on the screen. But with query its getting first tables data (Title & Description) but not images from table 2 just showing image space with that icon which shows us if image not found. Please check & reply me sir. bcz its not a big thing a small thing that we are missing there. Regards - Cue

Comment: no sir still not getting image sir showing me title & description but not image. please check again

Comment: Can you var_dump the query result and comment it

Comment: sorry sir im not getting what you are asking for var_dump.

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump your query? comment it means comment var_dump in here

Comment: sir in result im getting just image icon which display us as default if no image found

Comment: $qex=mysql_query($sql);
var_dump($qex);die; 
put above code after the query.
comment here the output here

Comment: i get this  resource(8) of type (mysql result)

Comment: sir you are checking for the solution or not ??

Comment: Is that all you got as the result?

Comment: yes sir with the var_dump code line that you sent me i used that after my query  and i get oly this one line of result -----    resource(8) of type (mysql result)   please check & try again to get the solution sir. Regards Cue

Comment: Tell me the output of this query. and also just to remind you I'm a girl.
$sql = "select t2.photo
from tbl_products t1, tbl_productphotos t2
where t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
and t1.tilename = 'Glass Tile' 
and t1.ProductID = 36";

Comment: ok mam this id = 36  has 3 images in the database table 'tbl_productphotos' & i get title ,description of this id=36  but not images.  default image icon there .Regards- cue

Comment: Did you try above query ?
tell me the output with var_dump code that I have previous given

Comment: mam i use this query $qex=mysql_query($sql); 
  var_dump($qex);die;   &    i get result is :   resource(8) of type (mysql result)

Answer (score 0):

titlename should be Title. check below query

```
$sql="select tbl_products.*,tbl_productphotos.* from tbl_products inner join tbl_productphotos on tbl_products.ProductID=tbl_productphotos.ProductID where tbl_products.Title='Glass Tile' ";
```

Comment: no sir Title is different & that is tilename not titlename & the tilename is different column .please check again not working

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. $sql= "SELECT * FROM tbl_products INNER JOIN  tbl_productphotos ON tbl_productphotos.ProductID= tbl_productphotos.ProductID";
2. $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_products ,tbl_productphotos  WHERE  tbl_products.ProductID =tbl_productphotos.ProductID";

Comment: get the whole code at my Github @ https://github.com/aice09/Useful-PHP-Scripts/blob/master/get-diff-tables_data.php